# dplyrxdf group_by does not work

Tags: r, dplyr

I do not exactly understand how to use group_by in dplyrXdf which basically provides the same functionality as dplyr for XDF files on R Server.

This part is the initial set up part.

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf", force = TRUE)
> library(dplyrXdf)

> # Write XDF file onto HDFS
> # myNameNode is an Azure storage blob (e.g. wasb://cntr@storage.blog.core.windows.net)
> hdfsFS <- RxHdfsFileSystem(hostName = myNameNode, port = myPort)
> inputDir <- file.path(myNameNode, "InData")
> outputDir <- file.path(myNameNode, "OutData2")
> rxHadoopMakeDir(outputDir)
> inputDataSource <- RxTextData(file = inputDir, fileSystem = hdfsFS)
> outputDataSource <- RxXdfData(file = outputDir, fileSystem = hdfsFS, createCompositeSet = TRUE)
> rxImport(inData = inputDataSource, outFile = outputDataSource)
```

And here's where we read IDs in from the XDF files (distributed over a composite set of 9 files)

```
> rxSetFileSystem(hdfsFS)


> ids <- RxXdfData(outputDir, varsToKeep = c("klant_id"
> head(ids)
  klant_id
1  1000293
2  1000293
3  1000293
4  1000293
5  1000293
6  1000293


> uniqIds <- group_by(ids, klant_id)
> head(uniqIds) 
>  klant_id
1  1000293
2  1000293
3  1000293
4  1000293
5  1000293
6  1000293
```

Why doesn't the group_by work? Just for the record I have tried exactly the same code in local context (i.e. not over HDFS) and it still doesn't group. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting `group_by` to do? It's usually used in conjunction with `mutate()` or `summarize()`. Are you trying to find unique values?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick! I have a massive file (>40 GB) and I need to find **all unique** IDs within it. Because it doesn't fit in memory I thought I would use dplryXdf which is just dplyr for XDF (highly compressed) files. How can I get unique Ids in my file using group_by and summarise?

Comment: Then you want `distinct()`, not `group_by()` or maybe a combination. `group_by()` by itself won't collapse anything.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much! I thought dplyr was supposed to be the SQL of R! In SQL, GROUP BY on a single column does the same as DISTINCT.

Comment: Wow. You can't do distinct on HDFS



`Hide Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error: distinct not supported on HDFS 
5 stop(..., call. = FALSE) 
4 stopIfHdfs(.data, "distinct not supported on HDFS") 
3 distinct_.RxFileData(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), 
    .keep_all = .keep_all) 
2 distinct_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), .keep_all = .keep_all) 
1 distinct(ids, klant_id) `